# Does Windows 11's new Snap feature only work with certain applications?

Tags: snap, windows-11-preview

Just installed the Windows 11 Preview, if I hover over the maximise button in Notepad, I see the new snap dialog:

[image: Snap working in Notepad in Windows 11]

But in an application like Visual Studio 2022 Preview (1.1), I don't see it:

[image: Snap not working in VS 2022 Preview]

Do applications have to be configured to support this, or is this a bug with the Windows 11 Preview build?

More to the point, do I as an Application Developer need to make changes to my application to support this feature in Windows 11?

Thanks

Comment: Your [intial](https://superuser.com/revisions/1659698/1) revision was broad the current revision is less broad.  The close reason simply was "Needs details or clarity" which you provided.

Comment: @Ramhound Agreed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that currently (preview build 22000.51) Windows 11 Snap layouts do not show when hovering over the maximize button for [applications using a custom non-Win32/UWP title bar](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/oa87w0/snap_not_showing_for_all_windows/h3fraak/).

You can use the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open the Snap layouts menu instead. I tried this on Windows 11 and it worked for applications like Firefox, Visual Studio 2022 Preview, VS Code, and Discord.

Comment: Thankyou, Win + Z works perfectly!

Comment: [Windows Snap Layout](https://aka.ms/AAd2eci) clearly has problems.  However, with that great feedback "it doesn't work", it will be a miracle if it's actually fixed.

Comment: Hah yeah I've been submitting and going through Feedback Hub as well.  Not all feedback is great but [this one regarding Snap layouts got a Microsoft response](https://aka.ms/AAd2ed3). The title and response aren't directly referencing the issue here but other feedback in the collection may have (unfortunately we can't see the whole collection). I'm sure they still have a lot of work to do on Snap.